# Cypher: Passing multiple parameters in WHERE IN

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jphp

How to pass parameters for WHERE condition?

That it is, this works fine:

```
match (b:Book) where b.guid={guid} return b;
```

But, how to pass multiple guids as parameters for this query:

```
match (b:Book) where b.guid in [guid1,guid2,gid3] return b;
```

I am using **[neo4jphp](https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp)** client, my code is like this:

```
$client = new Everyman\Neo4j\Client( "neo4j server address", "7474" );
$result = new Everyman\Neo4j\Cypher\Query( $client, "match (b:Book) where b.guid={guid} return b", array('guid'=>$guid1) );
$res = $result->getResultSet();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass an array as parameters, the query would look like this :

```
match (b:Book) where b.guid in {myMap} return b;


$client = new Everyman\Neo4j\Client( "neo4j server address", "7474" );
$result = new Everyman\Neo4j\Cypher\Query( $client, "match (b:Book) where b.guid in {MyMap} return b", array('myMap'=> array($guid1, $guid2, $guid3)) );
$res = $result->getResultSet();
```

Comment: Thank you. This does not seem to work for me. I will check again. I am using neo4j-community-2.1.5

Comment: can you try with this in your query.    IN [{myMap}]